# Prove the isomorphism of categories $Fun(\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})\cong Fun(\mathcal{A},Fun(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})),$

Tags: category-theory, abstract-algebra

I'm a computational engineer starting with a course of Introduction to Category Theory, and perhaps is extremely basic what I'm asking but I'm trying to learn how to make proofs in category theory working with the very basic concepts, but I just can't figure things out right now. Can you help me?

Thank you!

> If $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}$ are small categories, prove the isomorphism of categories
>   $$Fun(\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})\cong Fun(\mathcal{A},Fun(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})),$$
>   where $Fun$ denotes the category of functors and natural transformations.

P.S. This is excercise 1.11.8 of "Handbook of Categorical Algebra 1: Basic Category Theory" by Francis Borceux.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but not appropriate for this site - math.stackexchange is a good fit. Here's a hint, though: if I have a function which takes in an element of $A$ and an element of $B$, and outputs an element of $C$, can I interpret that as a function that takes in an element of $A$ and outputs a function from $B$ to $C$? You might have heard the term "Currying" . . .

Comment: Show your ideas and what you have done so far. Every step in this exercise is *forced* in a very strict (and formal) sense. In particular, no ideas are needed, once one has understood the definitions.

Comment: a category is any mathematical object, for example a field, a ring, a group, a set, a monoid, a function, a number, etc... a functor takes one category to another - they do not even need to be of the same type!.using the same level of generality the isomorphism of categories is true.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: "a category is any mathematical object, for example a field, a ring, a group, a set, a monoid, a function, a number, etc." -- this is very misleading, even wrong if you read it literally.

Answer (score 3):

Pretend that $A,B,C$ are sets, and that $Fun$ stands for functions rather than functors. Can you show an isomorhpism between the set $Fun(A\times B, C)$ and $Fun(A, Fun(B,C))$? Hint: if $f\colon A\times B \to C$ is a function, and now you fix some value $a_0\in A$, can you construct in a natural way a function $g_{a_0}\colon B\to C$? Once you answer this question affirmatively, your original question about categories will have essentially the same answer, only with some more details.

Comment: The morphism part of the isomorphism is actually more interesting and cannot be really reduced to Currying. It is connected to the interchange law.